# How to compare 2 result query with 2 while?

Tags: php, mysqli

I want looping with compare the first query and second query

I have 2 result query, I want to compare if id_car in the first query that is same with id_car in the second query

table1

```
id | id_car |
=============
1  |    1   |
2  |    2   |
```

table2

```
id| id_car  |
=============
1 |    1    |      


$query1=mysqli_query($koneksi,"SELECT * FROM table1");
while($data1=mysqli_fetch_array($query1)){

  $query2=mysqli_query($koneksi,"SELECT * FROM table2");
    while($data2=mysqli_fetch_array($query2)){    
      if($data1['id_car'] == $data2['id_car']){
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<input type='checkbox' value='$data1[id_car]' 
        checked='checked'>";
        echo "<td>$data1['id_car']</td>";
        echo "</tr>";
      }
    }
    echo "<tr>"
    echo "<input type='checkbox' value='$data1[id_car]'>";
    echo "<td>$data1['id_car']</td>"
    echo "</tr>"
}
```

I got output

```
checkbox  | id_car  |
   ✓         1    
             1    
             2
```

i want to output when data1['id_car'] == data2['id_car'] just show 1 data with checked like this :

```
checkbox  | id_car  |
   ✓         1       
             2
```

can someone help me, sir? I will appreciate if someone wants to help me :(
i try to not use SQL left join
and i want to learn to use 2 while with compare value

Comment: You can do it using SQL LEFT JOIN

Comment: @suhaspandit i know sir, but i want to try with while to looping

Comment: @suhaspandit can you help me ? if try with 2 while to looping

Comment: Any reason for you to not use joins ?

Comment: @Cid i got task to resolve that with 2 while, not with SQL left join sir

Comment: That's a terrible assignment. Anyway, when you echo the datas **after** the second while is your problem. This part should be in the `else` part of the inner if of that second loop

Comment: if you can `order by id_car`  you can compare results,  getting next record where id less instead to make inner loop

Comment: @Cid if put echo .. in else, i got double data in id 1 and 2

Comment: @splash58 can you give me example sir ?

Comment: I really don't support the way you are running query inside the outer while loop. It will result in running the same query for multiple times unnecessarily. Why not move the other query out of the loop first.

Answer (score 1):

With LEFT JOIN :

```
$query = mysqli_query($koneksi,"SELECT *, t1.id_car as t1_id_car, t2.id_car as t2_id_car FROM table1 t1 LEFT JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.id_car = t2.id_car");

while( $data=mysqli_fetch_array($query) ) {

    if($data['t1_id_car'] == $data['t2_id_car']) {
      echo "<tr>";
      echo "<input type='checkbox' value='" . $data['t1_id_car'] . "' 
      checked='checked'>";
      echo "<td>" . $data['t1_id_car'] . "</td>";
      echo "</tr>";

    } else {

      echo "<tr>";
      echo "<input type='checkbox' value='" . $data['t1_id_car'] . "'>";;
      echo "<td>" . $data['t1_id_car'] . "</td>";
      echo "</tr>";
    }
}
```

For 2 while loop ( JUST you code edit : Not recommended) :

```
$query1=mysqli_query($koneksi,"SELECT * FROM table1");
while( $data1=mysqli_fetch_array($query1) ) {

  $query2=mysqli_query($koneksi,"SELECT * FROM table2 WHERE id_car = " . $data1['id_car']);
  $bCheckedFlag = false;
  while($data2=mysqli_fetch_array($query2)) {    
      if($data1['id_car'] == $data2['id_car']) {
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<input type='checkbox' value='" . $data1[id_car] . "' 
        checked='checked'>";
        echo "<td>" . $data1['id_car'] . "</td>";
        echo "</tr>";
        $bCheckedFlag = true;
      }
  }
  if( $bCheckedFlag ) {

    echo "<tr>"
    echo "<input type='checkbox' value='" . $data1[id_car] . "'>";
    echo "<td>" . $data1['id_car'] . "</td>"
    echo "</tr>"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Var 1.**

Join on DB side

```
$query1=mysqli_query($koneksi,"SELECT t.*, CASE WHEN id_car IN (SELECT id_car FROM table2) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS is_checked FROM table1 t ORDER BY car_id");
while($data1=mysqli_fetch_array($query1)){
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<input type='checkbox' value='$data1[id_car]'";
    if ($data1['is_checked']) echo " checked='checked'";
    echo ">";
    echo "<td>$data1['id_car']</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
}
```

**Var 2.**

Join on PHP side (note, in your query the inner select executed for each row of the outer select. Avoid that)

```
// Collect all "checked" ids into an array
$all_good_cars_id = array();
$query2=mysqli_query($koneksi,"SELECT * FROM table2");

while($data2=mysqli_fetch_array($query2)){    
  $all_good_cars_id[$data2['id_car']] = true;
}

$query1=mysqli_query($koneksi,"SELECT * FROM table1");
while($data1=mysqli_fetch_array($query1)) {
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<input type='checkbox' value='$data1[id_car]'";
    if (!empty($all_good_cars_id[$data1['id_car']])) echo " checked='checked'";
    echo ">";
    echo "<td>$data1['id_car']</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

One loop with two ordered queries

```
function out($data, $checked) {
   echo "<tr>"
   echo "<input type='checkbox' value='$data'".($checked ? " checked='checked'" : "").">";
   echo "<td>$data</td>"
   echo "</tr>"
}

$query1=mysqli_query($koneksi,"SELECT * FROM table1  order by car_id");
$query2=mysqli_query($koneksi,"SELECT * FROM table2 order by car_id");

$data1=mysqli_fetch_array($query1);
$data2=mysqli_fetch_array($query2);
while($data1 and $data2) {
    if($data1['car_id'] < $data2['car_id']) {
        out($data1['car_id'], false);
        $data1=mysqli_fetch_array($query1);
    }
    else if($data1['car_id'] > $data2['car_id']) {
        $data2=mysqli_fetch_array($query2);
    }
    else {
        out($data1['car_id'], true);
        $data1=mysqli_fetch_array($query1);
        $data2=mysqli_fetch_array($query2);
    }
}  
while($data1) {
   out($data1['car_id'], false);
   $data1=mysqli_fetch_array($query1)
}
```